# R langauge how to create xgb.DMatrix object from data frame (newbe)

Tags: r, xgboost

In R, how does one create an xgb.DMatrix object from an R data frame?

Comment: Check the docs dear... And Welcome Aboard...

Comment: I did read the PDF and did not understand some parts. I code example would be helpful.

Comment: Checkout Kaggle R Kernels..., from the docs https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help but the link you provided did not have a code example of relevance to my question.

Comment: Just convert dataframe to matrix first using as.matrix() and then pass to xgb.Dmatrix()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

Assume that `y` is your response, and `x` is your data set of predictors (where categorical variables have been appropriately converted to numeric). Your data does not necessarily need to be sparse, although sparse data will improve computation speed.

Then `dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(label = y, data = as.matrix(x))`.

As you get more proficient with XGBoost you can start exploring the `weight` and `base_margin` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't do this directly. You have to start off with a sparse matrix or a libsvm file. See the discussion at https://goo.gl/kiHCqk for getting from a data frame to libsvm.